# Updated to Gulp 4.0 and now have a task build error

Tags: gulp

Im updating to Gulp 4.0 but I get an error when running `gulp watch`, that states: 
`AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: build`

The relevant code block in my Gulp file looks like this. What am i doing wrong?

```
gulp.task('server', gulp.series('build', function () {
browserSync.init(["css/*.css", "js/*.js"], {
    server: { baseDir: "./" , port: 80}
    // If you use vhosts use the line below and comment out the line above.
    //proxy: "demo.local"
});
```

}));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least this error in your code:

```
browserSync.init(["css/*.css", "js/*.js"], {
```

should be:

```
browserSync({
    files: ["css/*.css", ""js/*.js"]
});
```

[browserSync.init](https://browsersync.io/docs/api#api-init) takes an options `object` as its first argument.

**Secondly**,  the error `Task never defined: xxxx` I have seen this when, in your case, you call the build task - in your `'server'` task before it has been defined/registered.  So put the `gulp.task('build'...)` definition ( a registration of the task) before your `'server'` task.

Your gulpfile is erroring for this reason before getting to the other error in `browserSync.init` mentioned above.